# how to select multiple view in one recyclerview in android..?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, androidx

i done complete  work from tutorial  but it does not show any thing when i  run this code.. it only show button ..it does not show recyclerview .. i dont know the problem .. please help me ..thank you

I use this dependency in my project

implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'

> Mainactivity.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.res.Resources;

import android.content.res.TypedArray;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;


import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Adapter.ChangeStatusListner, View.OnClickListener {

     private RecyclerView recyclerView = null;
     private Adapter adapter = null;
     private ArrayList<Model> models;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buildResources();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        adapter = new Adapter(models,MainActivity.this,this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        findViewById(R.id.delete).setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
    }

    private void buildResources()
    {
        Resources resources = getResources();
        if (models == null && resources == null)
        {
            String[] text = resources.getStringArray(R.array.text);
            TypedArray image = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.image);
            models = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 0 ; i <= text.length; i++ )
            {
                Model model = new Model();
                model.setText(text[i]);
                model.setImage(image.getResourceId(i,R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
                model.setSelect(false);
                models.add(model);
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemChangeListner(int possition, Model model)
    {
                try
                {
                    models.set(possition,model);

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
               UpdateList();
    }

    private void UpdateList()
    {
        ArrayList<Model> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        try
        {

            for(int i = 0 ; i< models.size(); i++)
            {
                if (!models.get(i).isSelect())
                {
                    temp.add(models.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
        models = temp;
        if (models.size() == 0)
        {
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        adapter.setModel(models);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

> Model.class

```
public class Model


{

    private String text;
    private int image;
    private boolean isSelect;

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public boolean isSelect() {
        return isSelect;
    }

    public void setSelect(boolean select) {
        isSelect = select;
    }
}
```

> Adapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;

import android.opengl.Visibility;

import android.view.Display;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.ImageView;

import android.widget.TextView;

import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;


import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {

    public  interface ChangeStatusListner
    {
        void onItemChangeListner(int possition,Model model);
    }

    ArrayList<Model> models;
    Context mContext;
    ChangeStatusListner changeStatusListner;

    public  void setModel(ArrayList<Model> models)
    {
        this.models = models;
    }


    public Adapter(ArrayList<Model> models, Context mContext, ChangeStatusListner changeStatusListner) {
        this.models = models;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.changeStatusListner = changeStatusListner;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_layout,parent,false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i)
    {
        Model model = models.get(i);
        if (model != null)
        {
            viewHolder.text.setText(model.getText());
            viewHolder.position = i;
            viewHolder.image.setImageResource(model.getImage());
            if (model.isSelect())
            {
                viewHolder.view.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
            }
            else
            {
                viewHolder.view.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            }

        }
        viewHolder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Model model1 = models.get(i);
                if (model1.isSelect())
                {
                    model1.setSelect(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    model1.setSelect(true);
                }
                models.set(viewHolder.position,model1);
                if (changeStatusListner != null)
                {
                    changeStatusListner.onItemChangeListner(viewHolder.position,model1);
                }
                  notifyItemChanged(viewHolder.position);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        if(models != null)
        {
            return models.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public int position;
        public ImageView image;
        public TextView text;
        public View view;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            view = itemView;
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            text  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
    }
}
```

> MainActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="delete"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why your LayoutManager is horizontal?

Comment: because when i use Verticale its show me this error...!!
 Must be one of: RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, RecyclerView.VERTICAL less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info:Ensures that when parameter in a method only allows a specific set of constants, calls obey those rules.  Issue id: WrongConstant

Comment: i find the problem the problem is in condation
 if (models == null && resources != null)
        {
            String[] text = resources.getStringArray(R.array.text);
            TypedArray image = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.image);
            models = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 0 ; i < text.length; i++ )
            {